# Problema al crear fichero de logs con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quiero crear un sistema de logs en PHP para el programa que estoy realizando. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

require_once "connection-mysql.php";

$logs = fopen("logsimportarcsvarticulos2.txt", "a");

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");

$fecha_comienzo_programa= "La fecha de ejecución del programa es " . date("d") . " del " . date("m") . " de " . date("Y"). "a la hora ". idate("H").":".idate("i").":".idate("s").".\n";
 
fputs($logs, $fecha_comienzo_programa);

$sql="SELECT `ean` FROM articulos_csv_tests";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);

if($resultado){
    echo "La inserción en articulos_nuevos_definitiva de grupo_articulos y nombre_grupo en función de ean desde diccionario_auxiliar se ha llevado a cabo de forma correcta";
} else {
    echo "Ha habido fallos en la inserción de campos en articulos_nuevos_definitiva desde diccionario_auxiliar. Revisa en busca de errores";
    echo $sql ."\n". mysqli_error($conWebService); 

    fputs($logs, "Sentencia SQL de error: ".$sql."\n");
    fputs($logs, "Tipo de error en el SQL:".mysqli_error($conWebService)."\n");
}

$fecha_final_programa= "La fecha final de ejecución del programa es " . date("d") . " del " . date("m") . " de " . date("Y"). "a la hora ". idate("H").":".idate("i").":".idate("s").".\n";

fputs($logs, $fecha_final_programa);
fclose($logs);


?>
```

El caso es que cuando abro el fichero sólo me aparece esto:

```
La fecha de ejecución del programa es 18 del 11 de 2020a la hora11:49:49.
```

Resaltar que ahora mismo está puesta una tabla que no existe en la sentencia SQL, para provocar el fallo y comprobar que me registra en el fichero de log lo que le tengo puesto. Me llama la atención que sí se mete en el else, ya que el mensaje de error a imprimir por pantalla sí que me lo saca, pero me llama la atención que no escribe nada más en el fichero de logs que `$fecha_comienzo_programa`. Cualquier otra instrucción que le tengo puesta que me escriba en el fichero de logs no me hace nada. ¿Veis algún fallo en el programa? Porque no veo nada y no sé en qué estoy fallando. Muchas gracias, saludos.

P.D. Estoy utilizando PHP con SGBD MySQL y SQL.

Comment: Si lees los [modos de apertura](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php), verás que `w` hace esto: *«Apertura para sólo escritura; coloca el puntero al fichero al principio del fichero y trunca el fichero a longitud cero. Si el fichero no existe se intenta crear.»* Podrías usar `a`: *«Apertura para sólo escritura; coloca el puntero del fichero al final del mismo. Si el fichero no existe, se intenta crear. En este modo, fseek() solamente afecta a la posición de lectura; las lecturas siempre son pospuestas»* Prueba así: `$logs = fopen("logsimportarcsvarticulos2.txt", "a");`

Comment: Al poner ```a```` es cierto que ahora me sobreescribe el fichero, pero seguimos exactamente igual: sólo me pone el primer fputs de todo el código y el resto no me los escribe. ¿Dónde está el fallo? Gracias.

Comment: ¿El código pasa por todas las líneas donde escribes en el fichero? Si pasa por ellas debería escribir cada línea.

Comment: Aquí tienes errores, los saltos de línea `\n`, deben ir entre comillas: `fputs($logs, "Sentencia SQL de error: ".$sql."\n"); fputs($logs, "Tipo de error en el SQL:".mysqli_error($conWebService)."\n");` Y, no se recomienda escribir errores internos en archivos, si ese archivo de logs es accesible los hackers podrían explotarlo para encontrar vulnerabilidades en tu sistema.

Comment: Ahora ya funciona. Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lees los [modos de apertura](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fopen.php) explicados en el Manual de PHP, verás que `w` hace esto:

> Apertura para sólo escritura; coloca el puntero al fichero al
> principio del fichero y trunca el fichero a longitud cero. Si el
> fichero no existe se intenta crear.

Significa que si usas `w` cada vez se empezará a escribir en la primera línea del fichero, trucando su contenido (en uno de los ejemplos dice que si se escribe dos veces seguido se añade contenido).

Generalmente para seguir agregando contenido se usa `a`:

> Apertura para sólo escritura; coloca el puntero del fichero al final
> del mismo. Si el fichero no existe, se intenta crear. En este modo,
> fseek() solamente afecta a la posición de lectura; las lecturas
> siempre son pospuestas.

Prueba así:

```
$logs = fopen("logsimportarcsvarticulos2.txt", "a");
```

Aparte de eso, tienes más errores. Los saltos e línea `\n`, deben ir entre comillas, pues son parte de la cadena:

```
fputs($logs, "Sentencia SQL de error: $sql\n");
fputs($logs, "Tipo de error en el SQL:".mysqli_error($conWebService)."\n");
```

### Recomendaciones

- Viendo que escribes mensajes de error internos un tu archivo, considera proteger el acceso del mismo o evitar escribir errores internos. Si el archivo es accesible al público, un hacker podría explotarlo para encontrar vulnerabilidades en tu sistema.
- `fputs()` es sólo un alias de `fwrite()`, considera usar siempre las funciones originales en tu código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Álvaro. He borrado el fichero de log para ver si con ```a``` me lo creaba también desde 0, pero no me lo crea. No entiendo muy bien la documentación al respecto, porque te dice que si el fichero no existe lo intenta crear, pero a mí eso no me ocurre. El código es el mismo que antes funcionaba cuando el fichero ya existía, simplemente que ahora lo he borrado para ver si lo crea también. ¿Existe algún modo posible de ```fopen()``` que escriba en el fichero sin truncar a 0 y que si no existe el fichero te lo cree? Es que no sé en qué estoy fallando. Gracias.

Comment: @Sergio con `a` el fichero se crea. Puede que hayas cometido algún otro error. Ahora pruebo y te digo...

Comment: @Sergio, es como dice la doc, si el archivo no existe, se crea, cuando usas `a`. Si no ocurre en tu caso, debe ser a causa de otro error cometido en otra parte.

Comment: Sí, se crea perfectamente. El problema es que el fichero tardaba un rato en aparecer en el servidor. Muchas gracias Álvaro.

Comment: Disculpa, no sé por qué en mi mente te llamabas Álvaro. Un saludo, gracias.

Comment: Perdona, que se me había pasado. Ya la he marcado como correcta. Gracias.